# Apache Cxf different services to different packages

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I have such Apache Cxf maven plugin config:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingfile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb-binding.general.xml</bindingfile>
                    </bindingFiles>
                </defaultOptions>
                <sourceRoot>
                    src/main/java/my/generated/services
                </sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${server1}/Service1.svc?wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${server2}/Service2?wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I basically have 2 questions, maybe someone could answer those:

1) How can I extract those 2 Service endpoints to different directories? Now it would be "src/main/java/my/generated/services" for both. I would like to have: src/main/java/my/generated/services/service1 and src/main/java/my/generated/services/service2.

2) How can I setup that generated java files packages would be my.generated.services.service1 + (generated file package name) for Service1 and my.generated.services.service2 + (generated file package name) for Service2?

I tried to configure that using binding file, but only found solution for specific namespaces.. But haven't found anything more generic.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can change your wsdl?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I find to generate files to different directory is using two different executions of WSDL2Java plugin as show below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources-service1</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java/my/generated/services</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${server1}/Service1.svc?wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources-services2</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java/my/generated/services</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${server2}/Service2?wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks great! Do you have any idea how the package names could be set up?

Comment: You can use extraargs of wsdl2java and -p options there, please refer http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html and this http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html